# How to manually marshal an object with XStreamMarshaller?

Tags: spring, rest

This is in context of a rest client that uses org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate to make rest calls to a service.

It is using a XStreamMarshaller to marshal the entity into XML.

```
final public MarshallingHttpMessageConverter marshallingHttpMessageConverter(){
    final MarshallingHttpMessageConverter marshallingHttpMessageConverter = new MarshallingHttpMessageConverter();
    marshallingHttpMessageConverter.setMarshaller( xstreamMarshaller() );
    marshallingHttpMessageConverter.setUnmarshaller( xstreamMarshaller() );

    return marshallingHttpMessageConverter;
}

final public XStreamMarshaller xstreamMarshaller(){
    final XStreamMarshaller xStreamMarshaller = new XStreamMarshaller();
    xStreamMarshaller.setAutodetectAnnotations( true );
    xStreamMarshaller.setMode( XStream.SINGLE_NODE_XPATH_RELATIVE_REFERENCES);
    xStreamMarshaller.setAnnotatedClasses( new Class[] { User.class, UserRole.class, Role.class, RolePrivilege.class, Privilege.class } );
    xStreamMarshaller.getXStream().addDefaultImplementation( java.sql.Timestamp.class, java.util.Date.class );

    return xStreamMarshaller;
}
```

How can I use the XStreamMarshaller to manually get the XML that is being sent across wire before the HTTP call is made?